# Split string into chars in java

Tags: java

I want to read a big file that contains text like this:

```
QSSTNAFDQVS, h
SSTNAFDQVSA, h
STNAFDQVSAQ, h
TNAFDQVSAQG, h
NAFDQVSAQGK, h
AFDQVSAQGKV, h
FDQVSAQGKVI, h
EAILGDQFLKQ, h
AILGDQFLKQQ, h
ILGDQFLKQQY, h
LGDQFLKQQYV, h
VGKMAKSVMGH, h
GKMAKSVMGHN, h
KMAKSVMGHNW, h
MAKSVMGHNWV, h
....
```

My code:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(file);
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] values = line.split(",");
            String atributes = values[0];
            String cls = values[1].trim();
            for (int i=0; i<atributes.length(); i++) {
                char atribute = atributes.charAt(i);
                System.out.print(atribute + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
```

My problem is that after I split the string `atributes` and print them, these are printed in a random order:

```
S S D I T A S V N C A 
S D I T A S V N C A K 
D I T A S V N C A K K 
I T A S V N C A K K I 
T A S V N C A K K I V 
A S V N C A K K I V S 
.....
```

If I do the print and I don't do the split like this:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(file);
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] values = line.split(",");
                String atributes = values[0];
                String cls = values[1].trim();
                System.out.println(atributes);
            }
```

I get them in the right order:

```
QSSTNAFDQVS
SSTNAFDQVSA
STNAFDQVSAQ
TNAFDQVSAQG
NAFDQVSAQGK
AFDQVSAQGKV
FDQVSAQGKVI
EAILGDQFLKQ
AILGDQFLKQQ
.....
```

How can I fix this in order to get those values in the same order as in the text file after I split them?

Comment: I don't think the problem is that the attributes are in a random order, I can see nothing in your code that would be responsible for this. Are you sure this is the case? Is this the full code?

Comment: I have posted all the code that handles the file read. Also I posted the two examples before and after I do the split + the results I get. I took as an example the first lines of the text file

Comment: Where else could be the problem, because before adding the part where I do the split I get them in the right way, and after that I get them in a random way at each run.

Comment: @dres your code works correctly here

Comment: Your files are different those you are feeding to the two code pieces.

Comment: Could you add a `System.out.println(atributes);` just before (or after) the `for` loop, and prove that there's a change taking place?

Comment: I think this has something to do with the encryption of the file. As you can see the pattern at which the characters were in the file remains only the characters differ...

Comment: @EricHughes I have added that before the loop and it prints them randomly.If I remove the loop it prints ok

Comment: In the second example where you say you're not doing the split, you are still doing the split.  The only difference is that you're not looping and printing chars individually.

Comment: The output doesn't appear random, since your "random" output shows the same pattern of cascading characters.  Something else is going on.  You've said that you're running against large files; have you tried running this against a single small extract of the same files?

Comment: I tried on a new file that contains 15 rows and it prints them correctly. Very strange. So this has to do with the size of the file?

Comment: It has something to do with the file and your code ;-)  Is anything else using the file or the buffered reader (another thread, another process/program)?  Is writing taking place at the same time as you're reading?  Is the file in a non-ASCII or non-UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: I don't think that something else is using the file because I have just downloaded it to my compyter. Also the encoding part I don't really get it. How can I check? And how it should be?

Comment: Are you able to add line numbers to the file? (on linux, `cat -n filename > newfile`) Try running your tests on a file with line numbers added, and use those to see where the "random" (wrong) lines are coming from.  If you can dump more of your code (including creating the FileInputStream or whatever you're using) that might help, too.

Comment: I'm not on linux, I'm on windows. And I used `FileReader`

Comment: Well, write a program with a simple loop to copy the file line-by-line into a new file and append or prepend a line number.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the problem is that the attributes are in a random order, I can see nothing in your code that would be responsible for this. Are you sure this is the case? Is this the full code?

I ran the following code:

```
String line = "ZYXABCDEFGHIJ, h";
String[] values = line.split(",");
String atributes = values[0];
String cls = values[1].trim();
for (int i=0; i<atributes.length(); i++) {
    char atribute = atributes.charAt(i);
    System.out.print(atribute + " ");
}
```

And I get this just fine: *Z Y X A B C D E F G H I J*

Comment: Perhaps this should be a comment ?

Comment: You're right, I started with an answer when I thought something else was wrong.

Comment: Undeleted because I did check his case and I'm sure this code is not the problem.

Comment: Maybe I forgot to say that not the elements of the string are in a random order, but the lines of the file

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is elsewhere - this code - which clearly functions in an identical fashion to yours:

```
static final String[] data = {
    "QSSTNAFDQVS, h",
    "SSTNAFDQVSA, h",
    "STNAFDQVSAQ, h",
    "TNAFDQVSAQG, h",
    "NAFDQVSAQGK, h",
    "AFDQVSAQGKV, h",
    "FDQVSAQGKVI, h",
    "EAILGDQFLKQ, h",
    "AILGDQFLKQQ, h",
    "ILGDQFLKQQY, h",
    "LGDQFLKQQYV, h",
    "VGKMAKSVMGH, h",
    "GKMAKSVMGHN, h",
    "KMAKSVMGHNW, h",
    "MAKSVMGHNWV, h",};

public void test() {
    for (String line : data) {
        String[] values = line.split(",");
        String atributes = values[0];
        String cls = values[1].trim();
        for (int i = 0; i < atributes.length(); i++) {
            char atribute = atributes.charAt(i);
            System.out.print(atribute + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();

    }
}
```

prints

```
Q S S T N A F D Q V S 
S S T N A F D Q V S A 
S T N A F D Q V S A Q 
T N A F D Q V S A Q G 
N A F D Q V S A Q G K 
A F D Q V S A Q G K V 
F D Q V S A Q G K V I 
E A I L G D Q F L K Q 
A I L G D Q F L K Q Q 
I L G D Q F L K Q Q Y 
L G D Q F L K Q Q Y V 
V G K M A K S V M G H 
G K M A K S V M G H N 
K M A K S V M G H N W 
M A K S V M G H N W V
```

Could the file be being read by more than one thread?

Comment: this should maybe be a comment too

Comment: I think it is an answer - *the problem is not in the posted code*.

Comment: isn't your sentence in italics the perfect comment for a badly asked question?

Comment: @ᴳᵁᴵᴰᴼ - I felt the urge to prove it. :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems maybe you're taking the wrong file in input in the first code.

Can you post the result of:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(file);
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] values = line.split(",");
                String atributes = values[0];
                String cls = values[1].trim();
                System.out.println(atributes);
                System.out.println();
                for (int i=0; i<atributes.length(); i++) {
                   char atribute = atributes.charAt(i);
                   System.out.print(atribute + " ");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
```

Comment: It prints them in the same random order, both the string and the string splited

Comment: Check the value of file entered in new BufferedReader(file). If it's the same order, it's clearly the wrong input you're taking.

Comment: I have changed the file and the same thing happends. I don't understand what could be wrong with these files...

Comment: Try a file with only QSSTNAFDQVS, h and see what happens.

Comment: It splits ok. Also if I do on a new file containing smaller number of rows.I have tried on a file with 15 rows and it works ok